# Best software for designing drone shows

Tags: 3d

I'm looking for the best 3D software to design animations with 300+ drones. It would ideally be something with procedural design features so we can easily change the design by tweaking some parameters.

Basically I am looking for the best 3D procedural design software that can handle the following constraints in a nice way:

1. All the drones (that can be modeled as simple spheres, cubes or even points) need to keep a minimum distance to all other drones of 2 meter.
2. A drone can never move faster than 3 m/s.

I'm currently working in Blender, for which I wrote a plugin that checks the distance and speed constraints. I am however looking for some software that just makes sure these constraints are always met, while at the same time allowing easy manipulation of shapes and animations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting into your Blender model a constraints checker for the speeds and a collision detection either modified so that >2 meters between point sources are considered a collision or simply model your drones as some sort of physical representation plus a 100% transparent sphere with a 1 meter radius.

The Blender physics engine is quite capable of handling these sorts of restrictions. A very good starting point would be the [Boids](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/boids.html) engine and provides "Max Air Speed" and "Air Personal Space" movement constraints.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hzM7_vUxkA&ab_channel=BlenderInsight is worth watching.